# Access Android specific funcitons from custom Gradle script

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I have a custom `Gradle` file `custom.gradle` to load variables into `BuildConfig` and `manifestPlaceholders` like this:

```
ext.loadProperty = {propertyName, propertyValue ->
    buildConfigField("String", propertyName, "\"" + propertyValue + "\"")
    manifestPlaceholders[propertyName] = propertyValue
}
```

I load the function on my module's `build.gradle` like so:

```
apply from: '../gradlescripts/custom.gradle'
```

And I access the function within `defaultConfig` in my module's `build.gradle` like so:

```
loadProperty("SOME_NAME", "SOME_VALUE")
```

This throws an error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method buildConfigField() for arguments [String, SOME_NAME, "SOME_VALUE"] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

I am not sure how to access `buildConfigField` and `manifestPlaceholders` from that custom.gradle file loaded from another module's `build.gradle` file.

I tried already using the `apply from:` function on the top level of the `build.gradle` file and on the `defaultConfig` of the same file with no luck.

Am I missing something? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after tinkering I found the solution. I just needed to pass the androidExtension to the funciton:

```
ext.loadProperty = androidExtension, propertyName, propertyValue ->
    androidExtension.buildTypes.all { buildType ->
        buildType.buildConfigField("String", propertyName, "\"" + propertyValue + "\"")
    }
    androidExtension.defaultConfig.manifestPlaceholders.put(propertyName, propertyValue)
}
```

And then call the function from `defaultConfig` like so:

```
loadProperty(android, "SOME_NAME", "SOME_VALUE")
```